# How can you properly put a dictionary into a CSV file so you can search the CSV File by key values?

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to put a dictionary which has two properties of ID and Status into a CSV file. After putting it into the CSV file correctly I am wanting to search for a certain row by ID, then return the Status that is tied to that row's ID. The issue I am having is that during the for loop during the read, the row is a dictionary with  'ID,Status': '1,Off'. Since the field names and values are all together I can't really filter by a specific ID or grab a specific Status. I would like each row to be like 'ID': 1, 'Status': 'Off' I am either putting the dictionary in wrong or attempting to read it wrong using a for loop. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated since I'm still pretty new with CSV files! Thanks!

This is currently what I am using. It checks if the Csv file exists, if not, it creates and populates it, then attempts to read the data it needs. Otherwise it just attempts to get the data it needs based on an ID passed in.

```
fields = ['ID', 'Status']
dict_data = [
    {'ID': 1, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 2, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 3, 'Status': 'Off'}
]
    file_exists = os.path.exists("ports.csv")
    if file_exists:
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
            for row in reader:
                if row['ID'] == int(id):
                    port_status = row['Status']
    else:
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)

        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
            for row in reader:
                if row['ID'] == int(id):
                    port_status = row['Status']
    response = {
        port_status
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: int(Id) is the ID that gets passed in and will be used to search for a specific row/record. Also the reader block under the write block under the else I put there so incase the file doesn't exist it creates it, then attempts to read it.

Comment: You have said the behavior you're after, but you have not stated what problematic behavior you're seeing with the current implementation. Can you clarify that part? It'd probably make for a more concise answer.

Comment: Updated the question with extra details involving the issue and what I am looking for it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of trying to test the code & do some cleanup I fixed it.

```python
import csv
import os

def find_row_by_id(csvfile, input_id):
        port_status = None
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
                print(f"ROW: {row}")
                if int(row['ID']) == int(input_id):
                        port_status = row['Status']
        return port_status


fields = ['ID', 'Status']
dict_data = [
    {'ID': 1, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 2, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 3, 'Status': 'Off'}
]
input_id = 3
filename = 'ports.csv'
file_exists = os.path.exists(filename)
if not file_exists:
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in dict_data:
                writer.writerow(data)

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        pstatus = find_row_by_id(csvfile, input_id)

response = {
        pstatus
}

print(response)
```

A few changes I made:

- Got rid of the duplicate read code & put it in a function.
- `id` is a Python reserved word, so I replaced it with `input_id`.
- I removed the `delimiter` argument to your DictReader constructor. I did this because I couldn't remember what that argument did & rather than look it up I just wanted to try it. This could've been the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise using `pandas` for this, as lookups are quick and easy and do not require iterating all rows in a `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

dict_data = [
    {'ID': 1, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 2, 'Status': 'Off'},
    {'ID': 3, 'Status': 'Off'}
]

filename = 'ports.csv'
lookup_id = 3

if os.path.exists(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    print(df['Status'][df['ID'] == lookup_id].iloc[0])
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
    df.to_csv(filename)
```